# Limit $\lim_{x\to \frac 1 {e^2}}\frac{2+5\log x}{2+\log x}$ with Taylor

Tags: real-analysis, limits, taylor-expansion

So let's assume $$\frac{2+5\log x}{2+\log x}$$

This function has a vertical asyntote in $x=1/e^2$ but i am able to solve that limit  with algebric tricks.
So i taught that i can expand the 2 function with Taylor in the centre $x=1/e^2$ and then calculate the limit in order to find out the real limit.
My problem is:wich basic function i should expand? Logx or Log(x+1) operating some substitution? 
Thank's to everybody that will help me.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking - what do you mean "find the infinity"? The function has an asymptote and doesn't have a removable discontinuity. So $\lim_{x \to 1/e^2} |f(x)| = \infty$.

Comment: I am not able to solve that limit with algebric methods so i would like to try with taylor expansion or any other possible way.

Comment: Why would Taylor expansion be relevant? The denominator vanishes at $1/e^2$ and the numerator does not.

Comment: to find some different terms and assume that at the denominator will be something  that gives me 0 so after operating  n/0 i can find te infinity.

Comment: But you *already* have a non-zero limit in the numerator; if you can compute $2 + \log 1/e^2$, then surely you can also compute $2 + 5 \log 1/e^2$.

Comment: computing like this just give me real value,that's what i don't want

Comment: To be completely honest, I think you're trying to use a tool that you don't understand yet. If you don't know how to relate the fact that $2 + 5 \log 1/e^2$ is non-zero to the asymptote, then it's very unlikely that you're going to use Taylor series correctly. Moreover, Taylor series are (quite frankly) not a relevant tool here.

Comment: There are no tricks here, "$c/0=\pm\infty$" for $c\neq 0$ is limits 101. That's what vertical asymptote means. (Of course, the expression in quotation marks is formally completely incorrect, but gets the idea across).

Comment: The function doesn't have a finite *limit*, that is for certain. Could you perhaps be wondering about the *constant-order term* at that point? [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expansion+of+(2+%2B+5+log+x)%2F(2+%2B+log+x)+at+x%3D1%2Fe%5E2) claims that it is one.

Answer (score 1):

We don't need Taylor indeed by $x=\frac {e^y} {e^2}\to 1$ with $y\to 0$ we have

$$\lim_{x\to \frac 1 {e^2}}\frac{2+5\log x}{2+\log x}=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{2+5y-10}{2+y-2}=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{-8+5 y}{ y}=\pm \infty$$

therefore the limit doesn't exist.

Note that by Taylor's expansion at $x=\frac1{e^2}$ we obtain

- $\log x = -2+xe^2-1+o(xe^2-1)$

$$\frac{2+5\log x}{2+\log x}=\frac{-8+5(xe^2-1)+ o(xe^2-1)}{xe^2-1+o(xe^2-1)}=\frac{\frac{-8}{xe^2-1}+5+ o(1)}{1+o(1)}$$

therefore the limit depends upon

$$\lim_{x\to \frac 1 {e^2}} \frac{-8}{xe^2-1}$$

which leads to the same result in a more complicated and convoluted way.

Comment: Ok this algebric way seems easy but i am not that practical with subtsitution so would it work using taylor expansion?

Comment: @AndreyKudinov Taylor's expansion leads to the same kind of expression but in a more complicated way, You should become practical with substitution, standard limits, squeeze theorem, etc. before to apply Taylor. Using Taylor without this basic knowledge is just useless and dangerous.

Comment: Thank you for the tip..Anyway,operating the taylor method on this limit  would just require a lot of time or this is not a basic expansion that i can find on  the Mac Lurin tables of expansion?

Comment: @AndreyKudinov Indeed it is not effective and useful in that case, we know that the numerator tends to a negative value and the denominator tends to zero, therefore the only fact to clarify is how the denominatorgoes to zero. A simple substitution helps to calrify that the limit doesn't esist. Taylor is the last thing to use here.

Comment: @AndreyKudinov To find the expansion let $x=(1/e^2)(1+y)$with $y\to 0$ then $\log x = -2+\log(1+y)=-2+y+o(y)$ and $y =xe^2-1$.

Comment: Thank you for the patience.

Comment: @AndreyKudinov You are welcome it is a plesure for me if I can transmit some of my experience on that! Bye

Comment: You might also want to introduce Laurent series to the OP.

Comment: @Szeto I believe it was useful in that case to show something in more detail to convince the OP that Taylor is not the proper tool here and that a good knowledge of the basic tools is always a foundamental skill.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for Taylor expansion, nor for substitutions.

Since
$$
\lim_{x\to e^{-2}}(2+\log x)=0
$$
with $2+\log x>0$ if $x>e^{-2}$, $2+\log x<0$ if $x<e^{-2}$, and
$$
\lim_{x\to e^{-2}}(2+5\log x)=-8
$$
we have
$$
\lim_{x\to e^{-2}-}\frac{2+5\log x}{2+\log x}=\infty
\qquad
\lim_{x\to e^{-2}+}\frac{2+5\log x}{2+\log x}=-\infty
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$L=\lim_{x\to e^{-2}}\frac{2+5\ln(x)}{2+\ln(x)}$$
If we look at the top and bottom individually we see that:
$$\lim_{x\to e^{-2}}\left[2+5\ln(x)\right]=2+5(-2)=-8$$
$$\lim_{x\to e^{-2}}\left[2+\ln(x)\right]=0$$
so at first glance it would appear to diverge to $\pm\infty$

if we look a this closer we can rewrite it as:
$$\lim_{x\to e^{-2}}\left[\frac{2+5\ln(x)+8}{2+\ln(x)}-\frac{8}{2+\ln(x)}\right]$$
if we use a substitution $y=\ln(x)$ this becomes:
$$\lim_{y\to -2}\left[\frac{10+5y}{2+y}\right]-\lim_{y\to -2}\left[\frac{8}{2+y}\right]=5-\lim_{y\to -2}\left[\frac{8}{2+y}\right]$$
and this second limit is clearly divergent to $\pm\infty$ so the limit does not exist